# yii2 advanced console return

Tags: php, yii2, консоль

Категорически всех приветствую )

В YII2 Basic при обращении к консоли возвращается ответ

```
//например такое
php yii hello
```

т.е. возвращается то, что попадает в return. В YII2 advanced - исполняется код ( в поем случае работа с файлами, т.е. видно что команда работает ) но return ничего не возвращает

Собственно вопрос: подскажите, как получить return в консоли, в yii2 advanced

**UPD**
[По образу и подобию создаю файл, файл создается](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZhYp6cPD5E) но return не возвращает

```html
namespace console\controllers;
use yii\console\Controller;
 
Class MakefileController extends Controller{
    
    // запускается командой - **php yii makefile**
    public function actionIndex(){
  $fp = fopen("./cronjob/file.txt", "w");
  fwrite($fp, 'qweasdzxc123');
  fclose($fp);
  return 1234;
    }
}
```

Comment: значит у вас return не чего не возвращает. или до него процесс не доходит, в пишите в метод контроллера который вы вызываете первой строчкой return 123; и запустите команду

Comment: return как раз возвращает циферки. перед return команда, результат которой я ест-но вижу локально

Comment: echo 'сообщение'; return true;//решение с тостера